# SQL query not working as expected | Duplicates and wrong results

Tags: mysql, sql

HEyo folks.

alright, So i'm working on this little snippet of code here

```
        SELECT 
                current.name, 
                current.status, 
                current.votes,
                current.info, 
                current.votes_required, 
                current.sid as sid,
                current.previous_required,
                previous.sid as psid,
                previous.status as status
            FROM
                systems as current
            INNER JOIN
                systems as previous
            WHERE
                (previous.status = 1 and current.previous_required = previous.status)
                OR
                (current.previous_required = 0)
            '
```

Which Ideally I would like to show the results where either previous_required == 0 or where the previous_required's status == 1. However, for some reason, i keep either getting triple the results from my search (EG duplicates) or only a single result for the first one.

I'm pretty dang sure I know where i'm messing up (It's either the Inner Join or the OR statement). but I cannot seem to nail it down and fix the issue. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the condition from where to join

```
    SELECT 
            current.name, 
            current.status, 
            current.votes,
            current.info, 
            current.votes_required, 
            current.sid as sid,
            current.previous_required,
            previous.sid as psid,
            previous.status as status
        FROM
            systems as current
        INNER JOIN
            systems as previous
          ON
            (previous.status = 1 and current.previous_required = previous.status)
            OR
            (current.previous_required = 0)
```

Comment: That did fixed the main issue, thank you. I'm still getting duplicate entries but i'm just using "GROUP BY sid" to fix that, no big deal.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to link the current records to their previous records somehow. Does your systems table have something like "previous_sid", which links a current record back to a previous one? If so, you need to use that in you inner join. Something like:

```
FROM 
    systems AS current
INNER JOIN
    systems AS previous on current.previous_sid = previous.sid
```